# Background picture opacity for parallax scrolling

Tags: html, css, opacity, parallax

This might be a rookie question, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I'm writing a website with parallaxed background images and want to make said images a bit transparent as opposed to the text above them, which should be completely opaque. I followed [w3school's model](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm) (with some changes) and it works considering that background image is defined in the parent container, so the text inherits the image's opacity, as seen in `bgimg-2`.

What I've tried to do, appart from fiddling with the stylesheet to no avail, is to create a new container `section-img` that encapsulates both the background and the text, so their styles don't overlap with each other. This, however, makes the image's (`bgimg-1`) height equal to 0.

Here's an MRE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #282828;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.section-img {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/v3wjcf1p59841.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.bgimg-2 {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/o1a3xr4b39841.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7vw;
    letter-spacing: 2vw;
}

.section-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="section-img">
        <div id="title">No background picture here!</div>
        <div class="bgimg-1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="section-text">I want different opacities :(</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the sanest way to achieve this difference in opacities for both items?

Comment: maybe use ::before for your background image and put the opacity on that.

Comment: I can't see any changes adding `.bgimg-2::before { opacity:0.6; }` or the `after` equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you use "rgba" style(CSS input), "rgb" will set the colour of the background and the "a" command will set the opacity (transparency) of the image,  it can be set between 0-1 where 0 is transparent(0% opacity) and 1 is 100% opacity. i hope this helps!!

Comment: Changing the background colouw and leaving the image's opacity unchanged makes the image be 100% opaque as well as the text, which is my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bgimg-1 {
background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/v3wjcf1p59841.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 1;
// z-index: -1;  // you won't need this
// add position relative so that the ::before position absolute will be in relation to it's parent and not the body:
position:relative;
}

 // .bgimg-2 { // don't need this div
 .bgimg-1::before { // add this instead
    // position: relative;  // no this instead:
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    // end this instead //
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/o1a3xr4b39841.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work. Why are you adding `bgimg-2`'s properties to the first one? Why wouldn't I need the second div?

Comment: The ::before pseudo element replaces your second div needs, put your text in the first main div https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: I still don't know how to place the code and what specific divs you're referring to, sorry. Could you please share the whole MRE with the implemented changes?